# How can I express this as a linear constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, constraints

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a known vector. Let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$ be decision variables of an optimization problem. Let $Q$ be a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix. How can I express the constraint $$v^TQ^{-1}v \leq \frac{1}{s}\,,$$ as a linear constraint in $Q$ and $s$?

Comment: I think $s\in\mathbb{R}$ instead.

Comment: yes, edited, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't seem linear since if you take n=2 and v=[1 1] and Q=[x1  x2;x3   x4] then after calculations the constraint would be this $x_1x_4-x_3x_2\ge {s(x_1+x_4-x_2-x_3)}$